# Error "Unable to load DLL 'vjsnativ': The specified module could not be found." after converting application to .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, sap-ase

After converting my web application to .NET 4.5, whenever I try to use anything related to Sybase I'm getting the error message "**Unable to load DLL 'vjsnativ': The specified module could not be found.**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem by copying the **vjsnativ.dll** file from **C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727** to **C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319** and recycling the application pool in IIS.

Comment: If that doesn't work, do the same for the C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64 folder.